# jQuery changes my display inline-block to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, display

I have a problem, I tried at first to make a button to hide text, and hide itself, then shows a new button called 'show'.

I made them `hide()` or `show()` only if you double-click on them, so I also put a `<p>` to say "try to double click" which is shown only if you click once. I made it `hidden:true`.
Its display is hidden by default : `display:inline-block`

my html:

```
<button id="hide">hide</button>
<button id="show" hidden="true">show</button>
<p hidden="true">try double click</p>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
```

my js:

```
$("#show, #hide").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
    setTimeout(function(){$("p").hide()}, 800);
});
$("#hide").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".txtShow").hide();
    $("#show").show();
});
$("#show").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".txtShow").show();
    $("#hide").show();
});
```

my css:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

problem is : when I click on the buttons, my `<p>` has its `display` in `block`, and it won't return in `inline-block`

could you please tell me where I made an error ? and how could I correct it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `$('p').css('display', 'inline-block');` to make `<p>` display inline.

Here is your modified code. learn more about [CSS](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

```js
$("#show, #hide").click(function(){
   $('p').css('display', 'inline-block');
    setTimeout(function(){$("p").hide()}, 800);
});
$("#hide").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".txtShow").hide();
    $("#show").show();
});
$("#show").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".txtShow").show();
    $("#hide").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
<button id="show" hidden="true">show</button>
<p hidden="true">try double click</p>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
<h3 class="txtShow">SHOW</h3>
```

Comment: thank you ! it worked
I have now another question (sorry), when I click the button seems to have a greater padding than before, how can I make it that it won't move ?

Comment: It is because you are using inline-block. you can use  `$('p').css('display', 'inline');` if you don't want that extra padding.

Comment: thank you a lot again ! 
I should learn css properly instead of asking dumb questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, but as far as I've seen your code doesn't have the issue you described, the p element would return in `inline-block`. Please check this code as I used [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead to show/hide an element: https://jsfiddle.net/bhn08puk

BTW, I suggest you ask questions using online code snippet services like JSFiddle or JSBin so that we can quickly understand your environment including jQuery version, etc.

Comment: thank you for you answer, I don't know either why my p element didn't return to `inline-block`, but someone gave me an alternative with css, and it works, so I'll take it.

thank you for your advice, I'll be careful from now on to always put the Snippet.